# how to reorderablelistview when i have listview.separated widget flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, reorderlist

i have listview.separated how do i add a reorderablelistview? i try and something wrong with listview.separated, and this is my code

```
ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder:(_, index){

                    final int key = keys[index];
                    final TodoModel todo = todos.get(key);

                    return ListTile(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      leading: Text(todo.namakurir,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      title: Text(todo.namabarang, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
                      subtitle: Text(todo.noresi,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      trailing: GestureDetector(
                        child: Icon(FontAwesome5.clipboard, color: Colors.black, size: 20),
                        onTap: () {
                          Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: todo.noresi)).then((_){
                                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(      
                                  SnackBar(
                                    elevation: 8,
                                    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                                    content:Text("No. Receipt " + todo.noresi + " copied to clipboard", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)));
                            });
                        },
                      ),
                      dense: true,
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (_, index) => Divider(),
                  itemCount: keys.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
              );
```